# jersey/jackson - filter properties based on query parameter

Tags: java, rest, filter, jersey, jackson

Filtering out properties with Jackson is pretty simple:

```
final FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().
    addFilter(... the name of the filter ...,
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(... enumeration of properties ...));

<object mapper>.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(... the bean ...);
```

I am trying to integrate this in my Jersey REST application. The API user has the possibility to filter the properties by providing a query string:

```
https://the-api/persons?fields=name,age,location,gender
```

What is the most elegant way to do this in Jersey? I could easily execute the above in my resource methods, but this somehow kills the elegance of Jersey. Also, I believe that creating a new ObjectMapper for every request will have performance penalties.

I could write a `MessageBodyWriter` which fetches the `fields` query parameter from the `UriInfo` context and serializes the entity to json while applying a filter based on the `fields` query parameter. Is this the best way to do this? Like this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JustTesting implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider;

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE.equals(mediaType);
    }

    public long getSize(Object object, Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> aClass, Type type, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> stringObjectMultivaluedMap, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("MyFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("fields")));

        jsonProvider.locateMapper(aClass, mediaType).writer(filters).writeValue(outputStream, object);
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I am unsure if it is smart to do it like this. I am new to the Jersey library.

Comment: I am working on something similar at this moment. My solution actually also involves Orika (I want to save looking up lazey collections). As a result, I've implemented a manager that checks for custom annotations (like @Basic) on fields to determine if they are mappable, and if they should be filtered.

More specifically, on the Jersey side I am experimenting with com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.cfg.ObjectWriterInjector to apply a filter I've "MixedIn"to Object.class.

Comment: `.writer()` seems to not persist across requests which is good. I used `setFilterProvider()` by accident and that persisted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My current solution to a similar problem is to register the following servlet filter:

```java
@Singleton
public class ViewFilter implements Filter {
    private @Inject Provider<ViewBeanPropertyFilter> filter;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ObjectWriterInjector.set(new ObjectWriterModifier() {
            @Override
            public ObjectWriter modify(EndpointConfigBase<?> endpoint, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders, Object valueToWrite, ObjectWriter w, JsonGenerator g) throws IOException {
                return w.with(new FilterProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public BeanPropertyFilter findFilter(Object filterId) {
                        if(filterId.equals(ViewFilterJacksonModule.FILTER_NAME)) {
                            return filter.get();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public static class ViewBeanPropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {
        private @Inject ViewManager manager;

        @Override
        protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            Class<?> cls = writer.getMember().getDeclaringClass();
            return manager.isFieldInView(cls, writer.getMember().getName());
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little more gnarly than the solution you provided, but leaves the standard `JacksonJsonProvider` serialization in place.

It can be improved by pulling the (possibly) existing `FilterProvider` via `m.getConfig().getFilterProvider()` and delegating to it before / after your filter.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I did not know about `ObjectWriterInjector`. It seems to be some singleton/static utility class, made for adding filters prior. I wonder what happens if you call `ObjectWriterInjector.set` on a first call, but do not call the same `ObjectWriterInjector.set` on a subsequent call. Does it stay in place?

Comment: The calling code in `JacksonJsonProvider` uses `getAndClear` I believe, so it will be "consumed" on use.